# How to select DIV within adjacent and nested DIV's?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I need to select specific DIV's without selecting children/nested DIV's within them, using only CSS.

There are two DIV's I want to select individually. These are the DIV's containing the text:

- `image-content (1)` and
- `image-content (2)`

```css
.home_image_widget-2 > div:first-child div:first-child {
   background-color: gold;
}
```

```html
<div class="home_image_widget home_image_widget-2">PARENT DIV (wrapper)
  <div class="image-content">image-content (1)
      <div class="imageWidget_img">&nbsp; &nbsp; imageWidget_img (1)</div>
      <div class="home_image_widget_caption">&nbsp; &nbsp; home_image_widget_caption (1)</div>
  </div>
  <div class="image-content">image-content (2)
      <div class="imageWidget_img">&nbsp; &nbsp; imageWidget_img (2)</div>
      <div class="home_image_widget_caption">&nbsp; &nbsp; home_image_widget_caption (2)</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

With CSS, when I try `.home_image_widget-2 > div:first-child div:first-child {}`, it only selects the DIV for `imageWidget_img (1)`, but I need its parent instead.

I have spent a few hours on this with no success, so for all you CSS Ninja's, slice and dice me up a solution. Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to select .image-content instead of .imageWidget_img ? If so why not using only: `.home_image_widget-2 .image-content { background-color: red; }`.

Comment: I tried your solution (on http://fiddlesalad.com/css/) and it selected Everything under the parent. Sorry, but it's a No-Go...

Comment: I think I'm miss understanding what you mean by "DIV's containing the text: image-content (1) and image-content (2)", because that Div is `.image-container` and It contains `.imageWidget_img`and `home_image_widget_caption`.  Do you mean to select only The text "image-content…"?

Answer (score 0):

not prefect.

```css
.home_image_widget-2 > div {
   background-color: gold;
}
.home_image_widget-2 > div div{
   background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="home_image_widget home_image_widget-2">PARENT DIV (wrapper)
  <div class="image-content">image-content (1)
      <div class="imageWidget_img">&nbsp; &nbsp; imageWidget_img (1)</div>
      <div class="home_image_widget_caption">&nbsp; &nbsp; home_image_widget_caption (1)</div>
  </div>
  <div class="image-content">image-content (2)
      <div class="imageWidget_img">&nbsp; &nbsp; imageWidget_img (2)</div>
      <div class="home_image_widget_caption">&nbsp; &nbsp; home_image_widget_caption (2)</div>
  </div>
</div>
```